# C++ - segmentation fault reading binary file

Tags: c++, file

I got an issue, when I try to read  `char* professeur` in a binary file it fails, giving me a segmentation fault in the `read()` function. What's weird is that for all other `load` function in other classes to read `char*` members works just fine but for this one, even if the `professeur` is written correctly in the I got a seg fault.

So here is the code:

Cours.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Liste.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "Professeur.h"

class Cours: public Event
{
    private:
        char* professeur;
        Liste<int> groupes;
    public:
        void save(ofstream&) const;
        void load(ifstream&);
};
```

Cours.cpp

```
void Cours::save(ofstream& o) const
{
    int n=strlen(professeur);
    char buff[60], *buff2;

    o.write((char *)&n, sizeof(int));
    strcpy(buff, getProfesseur());
    o.write(buff, n+1);

    groupes.save(o);
    Event::save(o);
}

void Cours::load(ifstream& i)
{
    int n;
    char buff[60];

    i.read((char *)&n, sizeof(int));
    cout<<"n: "<<n<<endl;
    if(i.read(buff, n+1))//seg fault
    {
        strcpy(professeur, buff);
        cout<<"prof: "<<professeur<<endl;       
    }
    else
        cout<<"erreur read prof cours"<<endl;
    groupes.load(i);
    Event::load(i);
}
```

Comment: What does `cout<<"n: "<<n<<endl;` say? Are you reading past the buffer?

Comment: n gives the length of professeur in the file, and it gives it correctly. No the length of the test I useg was 14 so no not at all

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` should be checked to make sure it doesn't get larger than the buffer.

In `save()`:

```
int n=strlen(professeur);
```

`n` should be max 59 here - needs to be checked.

In `load()`:

```
i.read((char *)&n, sizeof(int));
```

Better check `n` here too (max 59).

Also:

```
int n=strlen(professeur);
char buff[60], *buff2;

o.write((char *)&n, sizeof(int));
strcpy(buff, getProfesseur());
o.write(buff, n+1);
```

Two different values are used to write the data: `strlen(professeur)` and then `getProfesseur()`.

You also don't allocate memory for `professeur` (at least not in the shown code). So `strcpy(professeur, buff);` in `load()` will fail too.

You might as well change:

```
private:
    char* professeur;
```

to

```
private:
    char professeur[60];
```

That way you don't have to `allocate` and `deallocate` memory yourself.

And make sure all strings are null-terminated.

**Of course**, if the exercise allows it, you can use [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead (`string professeur;`), and stream the data in and out using `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: I checked it in load and it's ok, so I haven't check it in save. Should I ?

Comment: @RemiHirtz - Yes, always check. Also check my update.

Comment: Ok so I checked n in save and load and the value is correct (14 for my test) and I replaced `getProfesseur()` by `professeur`. But I'm still getting the segmentation fault :s

Comment: @RemiHirtz - You also don't allocate memory for `professeur` (at least not in the shown code). So `strcpy` would fail too.

Comment: @RemiHirtz - Check my updated answer. You can use `professeur[60]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First you read the length of the name. Allocat as many `char` as the name is long +1 for `/0`, right to target. Read from file to target and append `\0` at the end:

```
void Cours::load(ifstream& i)
{
    int n;
    i.read((char *)&n, sizeof(int));
    cout<<"n: "<<n<<endl;
    if ( n <= 0 )
        return;

    professeur = new char[n+1];             // allocate professeur 
    if ( i.read( professeur, n ) )          // read directly to professeur
    {
        professeur[ n ] = ´\0`;             // write \0 at end of name
        cout<<"prof: "<<professeur<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
       delete [] professeur; 
       professeur = nullptr;
       cout<<"erreur read prof cours"<<endl;
    }

    groupes.load(i);
    Event::load(i);
}
```